# How to import Snipcart in React?

Tags: reactjs, import, snipcart

I try to use snipcart in a single product page (like [here](https://docs.snipcart.com/getting-started/installation)) with react.

With the code below a click on the button (class="snipcart-add-item") doesn't do anything. How do I have to import?

*In my version "data-api-key" is my correct snipcart api key of course.*

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import "./App.css"
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.snipcart.com/scripts/2.0/snipcart.js" id="snipcart" data-api-key="API_KEY"></script>
      <link href="https://cdn.snipcart.com/themes/2.0/base/snipcart.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

      <button
          class="snipcart-add-item"
          data-item-id="2"
          data-item-name="Bacon"
          data-item-price="3.00"
          data-item-weight="20"
          data-item-url="http://myapp.com/products/bacon"
          data-item-description="Some fresh bacon">
              Buy bacon
      </button>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `public/index.html` and paste your scripts and link inside the `head`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked perfectly